# Regex from Python in PHP

Tags: php, python, regex

I've got the script in Python

```
data = re.sub("[\xF3].[\x00]","\n",data)
```

How to use that regex in PHP?

```
$data = preg_replace("[\xF3].[\x00]", "\n", $data);
```

I tried it but doesn't work.

Comment: Try `$data = preg_replace("/\x{F3}.\x{00}/", "\n", $data);`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$data = preg_replace("/\x{F3}.\x{00}/", "\n", $data);
```

The `\xXX` notation should be written as `\x{XX}` and there must be [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) around the pattern, here I suggest using the regular slashes.